# How to build x64 app on x86 win7 system, using windows sdk

Tags: sdk, x86, 64-bit

Thanks for your attention.

I'm using x86 windows sdk 7.1 to build x64 app. here is my build bat file:

---

cd "%SDK_PATH%"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

call "%SDK_PATH%\Bin\setenv.cmd" /Debug **/x64** /xp

nmake /B /NOLOGO clean

nmake /B /NOLOGO

---

But the build tool is still using x86 environment, here is the cl.exe command line:

---

cl -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -GS **-D_X86_=1  -DWIN32 -D_WIN32** -W3 -_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DNTDDI _VERSION=0x05010000 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0600 -DWINVER=0x0501  -D_MT -MTd -Zi -Od -DDEBUG /EHsc DDRVMGR_EXPORTS /TP /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE /W0 /WX /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\" .\main.c

---

Any idea why this would be happening?
Thanks in adv.

Alex.

Comment: I cannot find nmake.exe in 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\', so the nmake.exe I used above is copied from 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\'.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the makefile messing things up. The `_WIN32` and `WIN32` defines are OK, they're always supposed to be there.